# How do I join multiple SELECTs in stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I need to send LOGIN_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS & LOGIN_ACCOUNT_STATUS always regardless of password (PassWD) match. The following script works correctly only if the password is matched. When it's not matched, it send all null (but I attempts and status). What's the best way to send LOGIN_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS  & LOGIN_ACCOUNT_STATUS when an email address is correct but password and or Status is not matched?

I could add another SELECT statement but the final result should be one line with rest of the fields null.

The following is from my stored procedure.

```
SELECT
login.LOGIN_USER_ID,
login.LOGIN_EMAIL,
login.LOGIN_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS,
login.LOGIN_ACCOUNT_STATUS,
GROUP_CONCAT(user_role.USER_ROLE_ROLE SEPARATOR ',') AS ROLES,
user_role.USER_ROLE_STATUS 
FROM login 
INNER JOIN user_role ON 
user_role.USER_ROLE_USER_ID = login.LOGIN_USER_ID AND user_role.USER_ROLE_STATUS = @AccStatus 
WHERE login.LOGIN_EMAIL = @UserEmail AND login.LOGIN_ACCOUNT_STATUS = @AccStatus AND login.LOGIN_PASSWORD = @PassWD;

SET @USER_FOUND = found_rows();

UPDATE login SET 
LOGIN_ACCOUNT_STATUS = (SELECT CASE (LOGIN_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS>@LoginAttempts) WHEN 1 THEN 'LOCKED' ELSE 'ACTIVE' END),
LOGIN_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS = (SELECT CASE (@USER_FOUND) WHEN 0 THEN LOGIN_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS + 1 ELSE 0 END),
LOGIN_LAST_LOGIN_DATE = (SELECT CASE (@USER_FOUND) WHEN 1 THEN @TransactionDateTime ELSE LOGIN_LAST_LOGIN_DATE END),
LOGIN_LAST_LOGIN_LOCATION = null 
WHERE LOGIN_EMAIL=@UserEmail;
```

Comment: At first sight this should work. You could improve the question by adding sample data for login and user_role as text to the question together with how you expect login to look after 1 successful password find and 1 failure (with call statements)

Comment: have you considered using output parameters instead of values from a SELECT?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine from what I can guess of the missing bits in the question - and here's the proof.

```
drop procedure if exists p;
delimiter $$

CREATE  PROCEDURE `p`(
    IN `inacount_status` int,
    IN `inuseremail` varchar(3),
    IN `inpasswd` varchar(3),
    IN `inLoginAttempts` int
)
begin

set @acount_status = inacount_status;
set @useremail = inuseremail;
set @passwd = inpasswd;
Set @LoginAttempts = inloginattempts;

SELECT
login.LOGIN_USER_ID,
login.LOGIN_EMAIL,
login.LOGIN_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS,
login.LOGIN_ACCOUNT_STATUS
FROM login 
WHERE login.LOGIN_EMAIL = @UserEmail AND login.LOGIN_ACCOUNT_STATUS = @AccStatus AND login.LOGIN_PASSWORD = @PassWD;

SET @USER_FOUND = found_rows();

select found_rows();

UPDATE login SET 
LOGIN_ACCOUNT_STATUS = (SELECT CASE (LOGIN_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS>@LoginAttempts) WHEN 1 THEN 'LOCKED' ELSE 'ACTIVE' END),
LOGIN_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS = (SELECT CASE (@USER_FOUND) WHEN 0 THEN LOGIN_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS + 1 ELSE 0 END),
#LOGIN_LAST_LOGIN_DATE = (SELECT CASE (@USER_FOUND) WHEN 1 THEN @TransactionDateTime ELSE LOGIN_LAST_LOGIN_DATE END),
LOGIN_LAST_LOGIN_LOCATION = null 
WHERE LOGIN_EMAIL=@UserEmail;

end $$

delimiter ;

drop table if exists login;
create table login
(LOGIN_USER_ID int,
lOGIN_EMAIL varchar(3),
LOGIN_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS int,
LOGIN_ACCOUNT_STATUS varchar(10),
login_password varchar(3),
login_last_login_location varchar(10));

insert into login values
(1,'aaa',0,0,'xxx','loc');
insert into login values
(2,'bbb',0,0,'yyy','loc');

set @acount_status = 0;
set @useremail = 'aaa';
set @passwd = 'bbb';
Set @LoginAttempts = 2;

call p(@account_status,@useremail,@passwd,@loginattempts);
select * from login;

  +---------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+---------------------------+
| LOGIN_USER_ID | lOGIN_EMAIL | LOGIN_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS | LOGIN_ACCOUNT_STATUS | login_password | login_last_login_location |
+---------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+---------------------------+
|             1 | aaa         |                    1 | ACTIVE               | xxx            | NULL                      |
|             2 | bbb         |                    0 | 0                    | yyy            | loc                       |
+---------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------+---------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

If you are doing something different in any way please enrich your question and comment appropriately.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It's working fine if I call it with the correct password. If I call it with wrong password, it returns nulls for all fields. But I want to login_attempts and login_status returned for the user_email. Everything else is null.

Comment: Not with you this returns expected output as coded for id = 1 where password is incorrect.